# Update Custom Post Type Metadata Wp Rest API

Tags: wp-api

I am trying to update a custom post type metadata on the front end using JS and the WP Rest API.

The object key is `wishlist_array` under `metadata`

Here is how JSON response from `http://ohalocal.local/wp-json/wp/v2/oha_wishlist` (my custom post)  looks:

```
{
"id": 1248,
.
.
.
"metadata": {
    "wishlist_array": [
        ""
     ],
.
.
.
```

On php I set the `register_rest_field()` function as follow:

```
register_rest_field('oha_wishlist', 'metadata', array(
    'get_callback' => function ($data) {

        return get_post_meta($data['id'], '', '');
    },
     'update_callback' => function ($data) {
         // Don't understand how to use the arguments here
         // How can I print or log the $data content??
         return update_field($??, $??, $??);
     },
```

And finally my `fetch()` function where I connect to the API. It returns no error and if I try to update the title, for instance, it works well. Only doesn't when trying to update the `metadata`.

```
fetch("http://ohalocal.local/wp-json/wp/v2/oha_wishlist/1248", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-WP-Nonce": phpVarObj.nonce
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ metadata: { wishlist_array: "add this" } })
      })
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(wishlistPosts) {
          console.log(wishlistPosts);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're supplying the request data/body like so, which is an array of metadata:

```js
{ metadata: { wishlist_array: "add this", foo: "bar baz" } }
```

and you want to update *only* the `wishlist_array` metadata, then you could do:

```php
// In your case, $field_value is the `metadata` value and $data is a WP_Post object.
'update_callback' => function( $field_value, $data ){
    if ( is_array( $field_value ) && isset( $field_value['wishlist_array'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $data->ID, 'wishlist_array', $field_value['wishlist_array'] );
        return true;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to update *all* metadata (or all fields supplied in that `metadata` array), then this would do it:

```php
// In your case, $field_value is the `metadata` value and $data is a WP_Post object.
'update_callback' => function( $field_value, $data ){
    if ( is_array( $field_value ) ) {
        foreach ( $field_value as $key => $value ) {
            update_post_meta( $data->ID, $key, $value );
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And regarding this question: "*// How can I print or log the $data content??*", you could do `var_dump( $data );` and check the PHP error logs — or `wp-content/debug.log` if it is [enabled](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log).

### Some Notes

1. In the `update_callback` function, the `$field_value` is the value of the `metadata` parameter; whereas the `$data` is the data *object* — this is equivalent to the `$data` in the `get_callback` function, except that in the `update_callback` function, the `$data` is *not* an array.
2. You may also want to check [this sample code](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#examples) on the [REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).
3. The examples above are basic examples and as stated on the REST API handbook, carefully consider what permissions checks or error handling may be required for your specific field.
4. With [`update_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) (ACF), you could also use `$data->ID` as the third parameter passed to `update_field()`.

Comment: Thank you Sally. I am now facing another issue with the JS. I created another question if you can help me. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/340855/updata-metadata-wp-rest-api